# Index variable (_i) in for loops?

Tags: coffeescript, undefined-behavior

Take a look at this simple code:

```
eat = (x) -> console.log "nom", x

# dog only eats every second cat
feast = (cats) -> eat cat for cat in cats when _i % 2 == 0

feast ["tabby cat"
       "siamese cat"
       "norwegian forest cat"
       "feral cat"
       "american bobtail"
       "manx"]
```

---

```
$ coffee a.coffee 
nom tabby cat
nom norwegian forest cat
nom american bobtail
```

It seems the `_i` variable is the current index. Is this a feature, bug, or NaN? I haven't heard anyone else talking about this, so I wonder if there's some reason I shouldn't use it in my code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

tldr-again; The author of CoffeeScript just told me [I'm right](http://irclogger.com/.coffeescript/2013-11-06): Don't use `_i`.

> ```
> 14:29 <jashkenas> You shouldn't use internal variables. 
> ...
> 14:42 <meagar> I was hoping something more deeply involved in the language would be able to put some authority behind that opinion 
> 14:43 <meagar> ... I was basically hoping for an authoritative "don't do that" 
> 14:44 <jashkenas> you just got it ;) 
> 14:44 <jashkenas> for item, index in list -- there's your reference to the index.
> ```

---

tldr; This is *at best* an [undocumented feature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undocumented_feature) for which a functionally equivalent *documented* feature exists. As such, it should **not** be used.

Your argument of "less typing" is highly dubious; compare:

```
for x in [1, 2, 3] when _i % 2 == 0
  console.log "#{_i} -> #{x}"

for x,i in [1, 2, 3] when i % 2 == 0
  console.log "#{i} -> #{x}"
```

---

> feature, bug, or NaN?

None of these things; it's undefined behaviour. You are *assuming* that `_i` will be the variable used for iteration in the compiled JavaScript.

You definitely shouldn't use `_i`, or assume `_i` will be defined. That's an implementation detail, and they're free to change it at any time. It's also won't *be* `_i` if your loop is nested in another loop; it will be `_j` or `_k` etc.

Most importantly, you can do this exact thing *without* relying on the underlying implementation's JavaSript variables. If you want to loop with an index, just use `for value,key in array`:

```
array = ['a', 'b', 'c']

console.log(index) for item, index in array # 0, 1, 2
```

Specifically, in your example:

```
feast = (cats) -> eat cat for cat, index in cats when index % 2 == 0
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to guess, or make assumptions, about what `Coffeescript` does.  Just look at the compiled `Javascript`.  From the 'Try Coffeescript' tab:

```
feast = (cats) -> eat cat for cat in cats when _i % 2 == 0
```

produces

```
feast = function(cats) {
  var cat, _i, _len, _results;
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = cats.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    cat = cats[_i];
    if (_i % 2 === 0) {
      _results.push(eat(cat));
    }
  }
  return _results;
};
```

...

```
feast = (cats) -> eat cat for cat, index in cats when index % 2 == 0
```

produces nearly the identical JS, differing only in that `index` is used along with or in place of `_i`.

```
feast = function(cats) {
  var cat, index, _i, _len, _results;
  _results = [];
  for (index = _i = 0, _len = cats.length; _i < _len; index = ++_i) {
    cat = cats[index];
    if (index % 2 === 0) {
      _results.push(eat(cat));
    }
  }
  return _results;
};
```

Both work, but `index` makes your intentions clearer to humans (including your future self).  And as others have argued, it is good programming practice to avoid use of undocumented implementation features - unless you really need them.  And if you are doing something funny, document it.